# How to configure datasource when using authenticationProvider in spring boot security?

Tags: spring-security

If I am using jdbcAuthentication, it will be auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);

Now I have two databases, one for app and one for security.

I can not find a way configure which database to be used by using authenticationProvider()

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("securityDataSource")
private DataSource securityDataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    // use jdbc authentication ... oh yeah!!!       
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    
}

 @Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.setUserDetailsService(userService); //set the custom user details service
    auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); //set the password encoder - bcrypt
    return auth;
}
```

How I solved the problem

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"${spring.data.jpa.security.repository.packages}"}, 
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "securityEntityManagerFactory")
public class DemoSecurityDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="security.datasource")
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.data.jpa.security")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean securityEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("securityDataSource") DataSource securityDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(securityDataSource)
                .build();
    }   
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"${spring.data.jpa.app.repository.packages}"},
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "appEntityManagerFactory")
public class DemoAppDataSourceConfig {
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app.datasource")
    public DataSource appDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.data.jpa.app")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean appEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource appDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(appDataSource)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your `DataSources` programatically and then use the `JdbcUserDetailsManager` to configure which one should be used by Spring Security.

In the example below, there are 2 `DataSources`, one using H2 and one using MySQL.

Spring Security uses the H2 `DataSource` since we have added the "security" `@Qualifier`.

```java
@Bean("security")
public DataSource securityDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/users.ddl")
            .build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("springuser");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("ThePassword");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
UserDetailsManager users(@Qualifier("security") DataSource dataSource) {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("user")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$GRLdNijSQMUvl/au9ofL.eDwmoohzzS7.rmNSJZ.0FxO/BTk76klW")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    JdbcUserDetailsManager users = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    users.createUser(user);
    return users;
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve it by separate the two datasources by creating their own cofig files and add the entityManagerFactoryRef and basePackages, so the app knows which database to get the info when certain entity being accessed.